# how to select not empty value input and hide input and show another input instead?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to select non empty input then hide it after click and show another input instead of hidden input.

Here is my sample code:

```js
$(".signupbtn").on('click', function(){
  $('input:text').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val().length == 0){
    
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
      //What I should add here?
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hideme {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.showme {
  display: inline;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input class="form-control showme" type="text" placeholder="text1" name="" value="">
  <input class="form-control hideme" value="Successfully Received!" readonly>
  <input class="form-control showme" type="text" placeholder="text2" name="" value="">
  <input class="form-control hideme" value="Successfully Received!" readonly>
  <input class="form-control showme" type="text" placeholder="text3" name="" value="">
  <input class="form-control hideme" value="Successfully Received!" readonly>
  <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the approach you take for your task is kinda *strange* here is the way to do it:

```js
$(".signupbtn").on("click", function () {
    $("input:text.showme").each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val() || $(this).val().length <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        
        $(this).next("input:text.hideme")
            .show()
            .css({"visibility": "visible", "display": "inline"});
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.hideme {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.showme {
    display: inline;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
 <input class="form-control showme" type="text" placeholder="text1" name="" value="">
 <input class="form-control hideme" value="Successfully Received!" readonly/>
 <input class="form-control showme" type="text" placeholder="text2" name="" value="">
 <input class="form-control hideme" value="Successfully Received!" readonly/>
 <input class="form-control showme" type="text" placeholder="text3" name="" value="">
 <input class="form-control hideme" value="Successfully Received!" readonly/>
 <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
 </form>
```

---

**EDIT01:**

To have a generalized solution for all form relevant items:

```js
$(".signupbtn").on("click", function () {
    $("input.showme, textarea.showme, select.showme").each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val() || $(this).val().length <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        
        $(this).next("input.hideme, textarea.hideme, select.hideme")
            .show()
            .css({"visibility": "visible", "display": "inline"});
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.hideme {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.showme {
    display: inline;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
<input class="form-control showme" type="text" placeholder="text1" name="" value="">
<input class="form-control hideme" value="Successfully Received!" readonly />
<textarea class="form-control showme" placeholder="text2" name=""></textarea>
<textarea class="form-control hideme" readonly>Successfully Received!</textarea>
<select class="form-control showme" name="" value="">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control hideme" readonly >
    <option>Successfully Received!</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: As you can see, even non empty values are selected too. How to solve it?

Comment: Oh sorry. i forgot about that condition

Comment: If we use remove instead of hide, then value of removed input won't send to database. how can we use hide not remove that we will be able to send hidden value to database?

Comment: @Jomla I've updated my code. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help. thumbs up

Comment: How can I use the same method for textarea? is there any other method for textarea?

Comment: I guess after that you ask me how to do it for (select). just keep the pattern you are using right (meaing classes and order of elements) now and just change the selector. I'll edit my code to show you how (EDIT01).

Comment: @Jomla I've extended my answer

Comment: wonderful. thanks for edited code. it's working like a charm. it's perfect! Thank you